# DBUnit: how to change a property value correctly?

Tags: dbunit

I have the problem with DBUnit (V2.5.3) that I want to set the property `FEATURE_ALLOW_EMPTY_FIELDS` to `true` but DBUnit ignores this setting. My code to set the property is:

```
DatabaseConfig dbCfg = null;
try {
  dbCfg = dbTester.getConnection().getConfig();
  dbCfg.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_ALLOW_EMPTY_FIELDS, Boolean.TRUE);

  System.out.println("getCfg -> " + dbTester.getConnection().getConfig().getProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_ALLOW_EMPTY_FIELDS));
  System.out.println("dbCfg  -> " + dbCfg.getProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_ALLOW_EMPTY_FIELDS));

} catch (Exception exc) {
  exc.printStackTrace();
}
```

I think the problem is that the new value is only set to the `dbCfg` object. But it seems that DBUnit don't use this object becaus the output of the code above is:

```
getCfg -> false
dbCfg  -> true
```

Looks as if I am too stupid to understand how to set a DBUnit property correctly ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `IDatabaseTester.getConnection()` seems to return with each call a new IDatabaseConnection object. I thought that this returns each time the same connection object.

**EDIT**

@JavaDev1987: Memorize the object returned by `IDatabaseTester.getConnection()`. At example use following code instead the code which I have post in my question:

```
IDatebaseConnection dbConn = null;
DatabaseConfig dbCfg = null;
try {
  dbConn = dbTester.getConnection();  // <-- get DBConnection
  dbCfg = dbConn.getConfig();    // use dbConn instead calling 'dbTester.getConnection()'
  dbCfg.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_ALLOW_EMPTY_FIELDS, Boolean.TRUE);

  // in next line: use here also dbConn instead calling 'dbTester.getConnection()'
  System.out.println("getCfg -> " + dbConn.getConfig().getProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_ALLOW_EMPTY_FIELDS));
  System.out.println("dbCfg  -> " +    dbCfg.getProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_ALLOW_EMPTY_FIELDS));

} catch (Exception exc) {
  exc.printStackTrace();
}
```

Important is that you don't call `dbTester.getConnection()` again, because this will create and return a NEW database connection (with a new and unchanged default configuration). That's what I wrote.

Comment: I know, right! What is the solution?? @JavaDev1987... please post here if you find out and I'll do the same

Comment: I have add comments to my code. Hopefully it's now clear what I mean with "memorize". Important is that you use the **same** dbConn object. If you calling the getConnection() method a second time you will get a new (another!) DBConnection object, which has a own configuration. If you change the configuration of the first DBConnection, the configuration of the other DBConnection object will be unchanged (because it's the configuration of the second DBConnection).

Comment: @Nova: Have taken a short look of your code. Cannot really see whats can be wrong, but I have a hint: Try to set the config value before you build the IDataSet. If this not helps you should create a new StackOverflow question for that (because your problem don't corresponds to my problem)

Comment: Will do, thanks for your time. I still learned from your solution.

Comment: For anyone interested, I've posted a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41471468/error-setting-database-config-property-for-idatabaseconnection-hsqldb)

Comment: @Nova for me it's work as             IDatabaseConnection dbConn = new DatabaseDataSourceConnection(getDataSource());
            dbConn.getConfig().setProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_ALLOW_EMPTY_FIELDS, true);
            DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(dbConn, getiDataSet(loadDBData.source()));

Answer (score 3):

I noticed there is an OperationListener in there, which is triggered after the Connection object is generated. Here's what I've done: I added a CustomConfigurationOperationListener:

```java
public class CustomConfigurationOperationListener extends DefaultOperationListener implements IOperationListener{
    @Override
    public void connectionRetrieved(IDatabaseConnection iDatabaseConnection) {
        super.connectionRetrieved(iDatabaseConnection);
        iDatabaseConnection.getConfig().setProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_ALLOW_EMPTY_FIELDS, true);
    }
}
```

And then setted it on the dbTester:

```java
dbTester.setOperationListener(new CustomConfigurationOperationListener());
```

That way we override the configuration after the connection is generated, and before the dataset is created.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method called `setUpDatabaseConfig()` in the `DatabaseTestCase` class, so I believe the intended way to set this property is by adding the below method to your class:

```java
    @Override
    protected void setUpDatabaseConfig(DatabaseConfig config) {
        config.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_ALLOW_EMPTY_FIELDS, true);
    }
```